# Are lifts continuous?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

Let $p:(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}) \rightarrow (X, x)$ be a covering map, let $f:(Y, y) \rightarrow (X, x)$ be a continuous map, and let $\tilde{f}:(Y, y) \rightarrow (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x})$ be a map such that $f=p\tilde{f}$. For my question, it is important that we do not assume a priori that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous.

The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042537/continuity-in-the-lifting-lemma-for-a-covering-map) question suggests that $\tilde{f}$ is automatically continuous, but I have my reservations. The setup I introduced in the first paragraph is slightly different, but couldn't we follow the exact same reasoning to argue that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous? Yet, this feels wrong.

I'll explain where my doubts stem from. It is well-known that if $X, \tilde{X},$ and $Y$ are all path-connected and locally path-connected, then $f$ admits a continuous lift if and only if $f_*(\pi_1(Y, y)) \subseteq p_*(\pi_1 (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}))$ (see Vick's Theorem 4.9 [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0881-5), or Hatcher's Proposition 1.33 [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)). Both proofs construct a map $\tilde{f}: (Y, y) \rightarrow (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x})$ such that $f=p\tilde{f}$. Ergo, as mentioned earlier, this should be enough to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous (see the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042537/continuity-in-the-lifting-lemma-for-a-covering-map) question).

Herein lies the problem: both Vick and Hatcher demonstrate the continuity of $\tilde{f}$ in a way which seems to vitally rely on the local path-connectedness of $Y$. If the fact that $f=p\tilde{f}$ is enough to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous, then why would authors as experienced as Vick and Hatcher make their proofs unnecessarily cumbersome? I am inclined to say that there is a mistake in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/331/jason-devito) answer.

Are my suspicions correct? If so, what is Jason DeVito's error?

Comment: The linked question is a different setup. For example, there is a path involved, but your question doesn't mention a path.

Comment: True, but I believe Jason DeVito's proof maps perfectly onto this setup. It doesn't really require the path. It seems to only need the setup I have introduced in my first paragraph. Using his very same reasoning, we should be able to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is locally the composition of continuous maps, and therefore itself continuous.

Comment: In Jason DeVito’s proof, to understand the behavior of $h$ near $u$ based on the value of $h(u)$ seems to assume continuity of $h$. So that argument looks circular to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course each $f : (Y,y) \to (X,x)$ has non-continuous lifts $\tilde f$. However, the question is more subtle. For simplicity let us assume that $Y$ is path-connected. In [Continuity in the lifting lemma for a covering map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2042537) a special lift is constructed by lifting the paths of the form $f_\gamma = f \circ \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is a path in $Y$ from $y$ to an arbitrary point $y' \in Y$, and defining $\tilde f(y') = $ endpoint of the lift $\tilde f_\gamma$ with $\tilde f_\gamma(0) = \tilde x$.

It has to be shown that this is well-defined (that is $\tilde f_\gamma(1) = \tilde f_{\gamma'}(1)$ for any two paths $\gamma, \gamma'$ from $y$ to $y'$). This can be done. See Hatcher.

Unforunately the result is not always continuous. See my answer to the above question.

However, it can be shown that $\tilde f$ is continuous provided $Y$ is locally path connected. No conditions on $X$ and $\tilde X$ are needed here.
See my answer to [Lifting criterion, where do we use "X is locally path connected" in the proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3584977) to find an explanation where in the proof local path connectedness enters.

Why does Jason DeVito's idea to prove the continuity of the lift break down? He correctly argues that $(f|_W)^{-1}\circ g$ is a composition of continuous functions, so is continuous. But in general it is not true that $h = (f|_W)^{-1}\circ g$  near $u\in U$.

Note that $(f|_W)^{-1}\circ g$ is defined on the open neigborhood $V' = g^{-1}(V)$ of $u$ in $U$. That $h = (f|_W)^{-1}\circ g$  near $u\in U$ means that $h \mid_{V''}= (f|_W)^{-1}\circ g \mid_{V''}$ on some open neigborhood $V'' \subset V'$ of $u$. But why should we have $h(V'') \subset W$ (which would in fact imply $h = (f|_W)^{-1}\circ g$  near $u$)? Recall the construction of $h$ via lifting paths $f_\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is a path in $U$ from the basepoint $y$ to $u$. If we can find a path-connected $V''$, then $h(u') \in W$ for all $u' \in V''$ because we can take a path $\gamma_u$ from the basepoint $y$ to $u$ and prolong it **in $V''$** to a path $\gamma_{u'}$ from $y$ to $u'$. But if $U$ is not locally path-connected, it will in general be impossible to find $V''$. This means that we have to take a path from $y$ to $u'$ which **leaves $V'$** - and then there is no guarantee that $h(u') = \tilde f_{\gamma_{u'}} \in W$. See again my answer to [Lifting criterion, where do we use "X is locally path connected" in the proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3584977)

Comment: Although this is a great answer, it does not address my main question. Even if $Y$ isn't locally path connected, can't we still argue that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous because it is locally the composition of continuous maps? There must be a mistake in this reasoning, but I haven't caught it yet.

Comment: @Jephph I made an update. All relevant pieces are contained in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3584977 and I just repeated them here. Also see my counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2042537.